# Auto updating MySQL column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

`userGroups`:

```
id  name  users
===================
1   abcd     2
2   efgh     1
```

`users`:

```
id  name  groupId
===================
1   Usr1     1
2   Usr2     2
3   Usr3     1
```

I am trying to make `userGroups.users` auto update according to the `count` of users in the group.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd rather run sql(maybe a view) that groups for the count.  If you do go the trigger route, how can you be certain it runs or doesn't get disabled.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to store the number of users in a group, that's certainly something you can query using `COUNT(*)` in the users table.

Comment: To the  two guys above me - it's smarter, faster and better to maintain the count result via triggers. DB does less, provides the same result. Also, if you're not somehow mentally disabled, you should be able to ensure a trigger runs. It's also *quite* trivial to achieve that.

Comment: @N.B. but there are possible anomolies to this. Sure, user_groups changes when I change users, but what if I ran an update query on user_group by itself, to make an inconsistent value? If I aggregate over `users`, I will get the proper results.

Comment: I don't know about you, but when I write code I tend to not do stupid things, like update my counter column manually or stuff like that. Unbelievably easy to avoid when you think about it. But then again, there are people that programmatically cover scenarios they will *never* do and there are people that are able to optimize their code using simple steps. To each their own.

Answer (score 3):

You can use update/insert/delete triggers to achieve that.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER grp_count_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON users
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     update userGroups g
     left join 
     (
        SELECT groupId, count(*) as cnt
        from users
        group by groupId 
     ) u on u.groupId = g.id
     set g.users = u.cnt;
 END
//
delimiter ;
```

You also need to do this for inserts and deletes.

Comment: How did you get all this from that? You must be on crystal ball v.9 or something

Comment: Good catch noting that it also needs to be done for inserts, but I suspect deletion as well, right?

Comment: it doesn't works. the `users` column remains the same.

Comment: @Strawberry: I find the question actually rather crystal clear.

Comment: @user2153436: Did you add 3 triggers for update, delete and insert? Make sure they were actually created.

Comment: A `groupId` cound have changed and the count changes from 1 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

When the users table is updated, check if the groupId has changed. If so, increment the count for the new groupId and decrement the count for the old groupId.

For inserts and deletes increment or decrement the group's count.

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_update_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON users
    FOR EACH ROW if(NEW.groupId <> OLD.groupId)
        UPDATE userGroups SET users = users + 1 WHERE groupId = NEW.groupId;
        UPDATE userGroups SET users = users - 1 WHERE groupId = OLD.groupId;
    END IF

CREATE TRIGGER my_insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON users
    FOR EACH ROW UPDATE userGroups SET users = users + 1 WHERE groupId = NEW.groupId;

CREATE TRIGGER my_delete_trigger AFTER DELETE ON users
    FOR EACH ROW UPDATE userGroups SET users = users - 1 WHERE groupId = OLD.groupId;
```

For the insert trigger you may need to check if a count row exists and if not do an insert with count 1 instead of doing an update that increments the count by 1.